# Como mostrar string até uma determinada ocorrência?

Tags: php

Quero exibir uma string até a ocorrência X, só consegui fazer isso desta forma:

```
echo substr($conteudo, 0, strpos($conteudo, 'quebra-de-linha'));
```

No PHP existe algum recurso nativo que consiga fazer isso? Para que eu não precise encadear substr e strpos conforme fiz acima.

Comment: Sua pergunta não está clara, poderia colocar um exemplo de uma `string` inicial e o que dela deveria ser retornado?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A função `strstr` tem o 3º parâmetro, que serve para isto:

```
strstr( $origem, $termo, $flag_somente_antes_do_termo );
```

Exemplo de uso:

```
strstr( '123456789', '5', true );
```

Resultado:

```
1234
```

Para aplicar em quebra de linha, substitua o `'5'` por `"\n"` ou `"\r\n"` conforme o valor de origem.

Veja os dois exemplos no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/N5rzgU)**.